# Why do Germans say "Es ist fast Wochenende"?

Tags: english-to-german

I would expect the proper translation of the phrase "it is almost the weekend" to be

> Es ist fast das Wochenende

However, my German-speaking friends tell me that the correct phrase is:

> Es ist fast Wochenende

(i.e. they omit the "das").

Why is this?

Comment: Do you say, it’s almost the Friday?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the adverb *fast*. The simple "Es ist Wochenende!" doesn't use an article either.

Comment: @CarstenS - *Es ist fast das Weihnachten!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because *fast Wochenende* is an adverbial in your example. Consider

> Es ist **nach acht Uhr**.
>
> Wir treffen uns **gegen Ende**.
>
> **Immer montags** fühle ich mich so krank.

If you used an article, you broke up the adverbial and made the noun an object (or subject in your example). One could ask for it then. People sometimes do this to provoke a question:

> Es ist fast **das Wochenende**. — Welches Wochenende? — Vor den Ferien.

If you don't want this, don't use an article.